# writing utf-8 encoded text to a file

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, string-formatting

I am trying to print chinese text to a file. When i print it on the terminal, it looks correct to me. When i type `print >> filename...` i get this error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)`

I dont know what else i need to do.. i already encoded all textual data to `utf-8` and used string formatting.

This is my code:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

```
exclude = string.punctuation

    def get_documents_cleaned(topics,filename):
        c = codecs.open(filename, "w", "utf-8")
        for top in topics:
            print >> c , "num" , "," , "text" , "," , "id" , "," , top
            document_results = proj.get('docs',text=top)['results']
            for doc in document_results:
                print "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(doc[1], (doc[0]['text']).encode('utf-8').translate(None,exclude), doc[0]['document']['id'], top.encode('utf-8'))
                print >> c , "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(doc[1], (doc[0]['text']).encode('utf-8').translate(None,exclude), doc[0]['document']['id'], top.encode('utf-8'))

get_documents_cleaned(my_topics,"export_c.csv")
```

`print doc[0]['text']` looks like this:

`u' \u3001  \u6010...'`

Comment: Which line in your program does it claim the error occurred on? Cause I'd guess it's probably on the `print "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(doc[1], ...` line.

Comment: its on this line:                 `print >> c , "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(doc[1], (doc[0['text']).encode('utf-8').translate(None,exclude), doc[0]['document']['id'], top.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: I think the issue is that the string literal you are formatting into is not a unicode object. Try putting a u in front of the first double quote. Ideally you should be decoding data as your program receives it from other sources (into unicode objects). Then encode the data (into utf-8) when you send it out.

Comment: like this? `print >> c , u"{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(doc[1], ...` It didnt work

Comment: How does `doc[0['text'])` even work?

Comment: Ah.. yeah I missed the typo. I have no idea how that's even running.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part in putting the code into stackoverflow

Comment: Can you change your print >> c to just c.write("...") ? I'm skeptical of the redirect operator here. Also try opening the file as 'wb' instead of 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first print statement works, it's clear, that it's not the format function raising the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Instead it's a problem with the file writer. `c` seems expect a `unicode` object but only gets a UTF-8 encoded `str` object (let's name it `s`). So `c` tries to call `s.decode()` implicitly which results in the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

You could fix your problem by simply calling `s.decode('utf-8')` before printing or by using the Python default `open(filename, "w")` function instead.